# Combine CSS and JS files from plugins

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

I want to combine all my CSS and JS files.
Given the fact that I use different plugins I don't see a way to do this manually because after an update of the plugin I have to start all over.

So I did some Googling but didn't find a satisfying answer to my problem.

Can anybody tell me how to combine all my CSS and JS files?
I have no experience with this so... kinda stuck.

M.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [Autoptimize](https://wordpress.org/plugins/autoptimize/) WordPress plugin or [W3 Total Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/) WordPress plugin, with W3 Total cache enable minify option. They both support combining and minifying all enqueued Scripts (JS) and Stylesheet (CSS)

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. Thank you for your answer. I went with WP Fastest Cache